# How do I modify existing column definitions graphically in BIDS/SSIS Flat Files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, visual-studio-2005, bids

In BIDS 2005, I use a lot of fixed-width flat file sources. When initially creating the connection manager, in the graphical 'Columns' pane, I can click to insert each column delimiter where needed. Clicking 'OK' saves perfectly fine.

However, when editing an **existing** flat file connection, I can see and move existing column delimiters on the 'Columns' pane, but can no longer add new ones. Instead, I must go to the 'Advanced' pane, and add columns manually, while having to keep clicking back and forth to the 'Columns' pane to see where the delimiters need to go.

Is this normal behavior in BIDS? Is there a work-around, or am I stuck with the 'Advanced' pane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way to add column to existing fixed width flat file. This is true for SQL Server 2008 R2, also. I am not aware of such improvement in 2012 version.

So you are left with adding column in Advanced pane or using Reset columns button to set all the columns again.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but it does seem that there is no way. Thank you.